# How to prevent multiple click on Switch component from react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an issue with Switch component from react native, the issue is user able to multiple click on switch component before API completed. So, how to prevent user to multiple click on switch component?

I'm using class component btw.

```
              <Switch
                trackColor={{ false: MONOCHROME_5, true: POLYCHROME_1 }}
                ios_backgroundColor={MONOCHROME_5}
                onValueChange={() => {
                  //do something
                }}
                onChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
                value={this.state.enabled}
              />
```

Already try to use state to disable the component with onTouchStart props,  but it was still able to multiple click

Answer (score 2):

Use a `useState` hook to hold the state of a boolean value which will set the switch's `disabled` prop. You can then toggle this boolean in your `onChange` or `onValueChange` function to disable the switch, and then re-enable once the API call has completed.

```
const [switchDisabled, setSwitchDisabled] = useState(false)

<Switch
    trackColor={{ false: MONOCHROME_5, true: POLYCHROME_1 }}
    ios_backgroundColor={MONOCHROME_5}
    onValueChange={() => {
        setSwitchDisabled(true)
        //await API Call
        setSwitchDisabled(false)
    }}
    onChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
    value={this.state.enabled}
    disabled={switchDisabled}
/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, mine using class component :(

Comment: Please edit your question to provide that detail then

Comment: I already tried your ways but its not working for me

Comment: Change `const [switchDisabled, setSwitchDisabled] = useState(false)` to `this.state.switchDisabled = false`, the `setSwitchDisabled()` lines to `this.state.switchDisabled = [true/false]`, and finally, `disabled = this.state.switchDisabled`

Comment: I found out how to handle it, added some props to prevent it, the concept almost like yours. Thanks for giving me the clue

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from my partner

here is the way

```
              <Switch
                disabled={this.state.isDisableToggle}
                onResponderStart={() => {
                  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') { // handle prevent click toggle for ios activated
                    this.setState({ isDisableToggle: true })
                  }
                }}
                onChange={() => {
                  if (Platform.OS === 'android') { // handle prevent click toggle android activated
                    this.setState({ isDisableToggle: true })
                  }
                }}
                onValueChange={() => {
                  setTimeout(() => { // handle prevent click toggle disabled
                    this.setState({ isDisableToggle: false });
                  }, 2000);
                  // do something
                }}
                value={this.state.isEnabledSwitch}
              />
```

it was almost same with concept from @Stitt, but we found out how to prevent double click from iOS and android device